# In Deus Ex, I'm stuck with binoculars zoom on

Tags: deus-ex

Somehow I managed to get stuck with a binocular's point of view. (Compare what I see [with binoculars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWCTb.jpg) and [without binoculars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9xw7.jpg).)

Saving and loading didn't help. Restarting the game didn't help. How can I get back to the normal field of view?

Answer (score 2):

Switch to a different item using hotkeys or the inventory menu.